# Python min fucntion with lambda if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

```
a = 4    
compare = min((a//3), (a//5), key=lambda x: x if x * 3 == a or x * 5 == a else a)
```

why compare is 1?
i'm just think about it,

a // 3 = 1 -> x

a // 5 = 0 -> x2

My prediction

- key's lambda function, x becomes to 4, and x2 becomes to 4
  so, min function pick x and finally compare = 4

but, it say compare = 1.

How can compare be 1?

Comment: You are passing `1` and `0` to the min function. How could the result be `4`?

Comment: The `key` is only used to make the decision, it's not the value that will be returned. The return value is one of the values you initially pass in.

Comment: i'm think `key` effects to value. thanks for comments! now i'm fully understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function as key, it transforms the arguments you pass to whatever the function returns, then executes `min` on them, but `min` does **not** return one of the transformed values, it returns one of the ones you initially passed.